# How to apply custom css to the title attribute of textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to apply custom css to the title attribute of textbox in an asp.net mvc view using jquery.

Can anyone help me to get some sample code in order to apply the custom css to the title attribute of the textbox.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kuamr Patro

Comment: The browser controls the behavior of the default title attribute popup.  You can override this functionality w/ a customizable tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to achieve that.

**[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/EZpsy/)**.

Example HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." />
</p>
```

Applied style:

```
.ui-tooltip {
    background: green;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
}
```

Requred JavaScript (to activate tooltip):

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

Don't forget to import the necessary scripts (and desired CSS themes):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: So.. did you try this out/considered it? If it's not proper, then I should delete the answer.